# CakePHP/JQuery: AJAX working correctly in Chrome/Firefox but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp, jquery

**Context**

For a research project we're computing product recommendations for Users. While those recommendations are created (method `createList` called via AJAX) the User should see a waiting page. After the `createList` action returns, he should be redirected to the result (`showList`). This is working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE (Version 9 on Win7). It seems like it is calling both actions synchronously.

**Code**

I'm using JQuery together with CakePHP 1.3 via JsHelper.
This is the JsHelper code in the view for the waiting page:

```
echo $this->Js->domReady($this->Js->request(    array('controller' => 'probands', 'action' => 'createList', $pid),
                                                array('complete' => $this->Js->redirect(array('controller' => 'probands', 'action' => 'showList', $pid)))
                                        )
                    );
```

And this is the resulting JavaScript created by CakePHP's JsHelper:

```
$(document).ready(function () {$.ajax({complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {window.location = "/socrec/probands/showList/1";}, url:"\/socrec\/probands\/createList\/1"});});
```

Can you give me some hint of how I can improve the solution so it is working in IE as well? Also, if you have general comments for a better implementation of what I want to achieve, I'm happy to hear those too as I'm still quite new to AJAX. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, it is working now. Unfortunately, I don't know why. Maybe there was an error in the server code only affecting IE, though this seems unlikely to me. However, the question thus became obsolete, sorry.

Comment: I've been too fast. It happened again. It seems like IE is not reliably calling `createList`. Is anybody able to guess what could be the reason?